# An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext - Spring 3.2.2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to invoke a protected method from a class that implements the `ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent>` interface on successful login (Spring 3.2.2 and Spring Security 3.2.0 M1). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15493237/1391249) is my previous question.

The application runs under the following environment.

- Spring 3.2.2
- Spring Security 3.2.0
- JPA 2.0
- JSF 2.1.9
- MySQL 5.6.11
- JDK-7u11
- NetBeans 7.2.1

I have added the following libraries related to Spring security to the classpath.

- spring-security-core-3.2.0.M1.jar
- spring-security-config-3.2.0.M1.jar
- spring-security-web-3.2.0.M1.jar

---

The class that implements `ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent>` is as follows.

```
package loginsuccesshandler;

import admin.dao.service.StateService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationSuccessEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public final class AuthSuccessHandler implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent>
{
    @Autowired
    private StateService stateService;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) 
    {
        System.out.println(event.getAuthentication());
        System.out.println("rowCount = "+stateService.rowCount());
    }
}
```

This prevents a user from being logged in even with correct credentials with the following message (it is just an example. Counting the number of states upon successful authentication is not required at all).

> An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

---

The event is raised. The first statement inside the `onApplicationEvent()` method displays the following.

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@45264a59: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f:Username: admin; 
Password: [PROTECTED]; 
Enabled: true; 
AccountNonExpired: true; 
credentialsNonExpired: true; 
AccountNonLocked: true; 
Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; 
Credentials: [PROTECTED]; 
Authenticated: true; 
Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; 
SessionId: 88777A678DC5BB0272F84CA4BC61FAF2;
Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN
```

So it appears that the user is authenticated and the authentication object is available.

---

My `springSecurity.xml` file simply looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http pattern="/utility/Login.jsf*" security="none"/>
    <debug/>
    <http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
        </session-management>

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin_side/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" requires-channel="any"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/utility/Login.jsf" access="permitAll" requires-channel="any"/>
        <http-basic />
        <anonymous />

        <form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/utility/Login.jsf" authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler" authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/utility/Login.jsf" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
       <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
               users-by-username-query="select email_id, password, enabled from user_table where lower(email_id)=lower(?)"
               authorities-by-username-query="select ut.email_id, ur.authority from user_table ut, user_roles ur where ut.user_id=ur.user_id and lower(ut.email_id)=lower(?)"/>
       </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="loginSuccessHandler" class="loginsuccesshandler.LoginSuccessHandler"/>
    <beans:bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="loginsuccesshandler.AuthenticationFailureHandler" />        

    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="false">
        <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* admin.dao.*.*(..))" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    </global-method-security>
</beans:beans>
```

---

The Spring security works fine, when the following lines of XML is omitted from the `spring-security.xml` file.

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="false">
     <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* admin.dao.*.*(..))" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
</global-method-security>
```

Can a protected method (with method security applied) be invoked from a class implementing the `ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent>` interface? If yes, then what is missing in my case? I have clicked thousands of links so far but couldn't find a single clue.

---

The `application-context.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="admin.mangedbean loginsuccesshandler" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice" type="annotation"/>  
    </context:component-scan>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>            

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory" >
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
              <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
            </map>
        </property>

        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/social_networking"/>
    </bean>

    <!--The bean shown in the beginning is configured here-->
    <bean id="authSuccessHandler" class="loginsuccesshandler.AuthSuccessHandler"/> 

    <bean id="testService" class="admin.dao.TestDAO"/>
    <bean id="stateService" class="admin.dao.StateDAO"/>
    <bean id="sharableService" class="admin.dao.SharableDAO"/>
</beans>
```

---

The `web.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">        

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <!--<param-value>Development</param-value>-->
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>        

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Restrict direct access to XHTML files</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>XHTML files</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint />
    </security-constraint> 

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            120
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/utility/Login.jsf</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/social_networking</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

---

The debug information can be seen below, when an attempt is made to login which ultimately fails.

```
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (AntPathRequestMatcher.java:116) - Checking match of request : '/j_spring_security_check'; against '/utility/login.jsf*'
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (AntPathRequestMatcher.java:116) - Checking match of request : '/j_spring_security_check'; against '/utility/login.jsf*'
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (FilterChainProxy.java:337) - /j_spring_security_check at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ChannelProcessingFilter'
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (AntPathRequestMatcher.java:116) - Checking match of request : '/j_spring_security_check'; against '/admin_side/**'
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (AntPathRequestMatcher.java:116) - Checking match of request : '/j_spring_security_check'; against '/utility/login.jsf'
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (FilterChainProxy.java:337) - /j_spring_security_check at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:139) - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:85) - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@1103da5. A new one will be created.
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (FilterChainProxy.java:337) - /j_spring_security_check at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ConcurrentSessionFilter'
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (FilterChainProxy.java:337) - /j_spring_security_check at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (FilterChainProxy.java:337) - /j_spring_security_check at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (FilterChainProxy.java:337) - /j_spring_security_check at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:189) - Request is to process authentication
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (ProviderManager.java:152) - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (JdbcTemplate.java:637) - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (JdbcTemplate.java:572) - Executing prepared SQL statement [select email_id, password, enabled from user_table where lower(email_id)=lower(?)]
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (DataSourceUtils.java:110) - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (DataSourceUtils.java:327) - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (JdbcTemplate.java:637) - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (JdbcTemplate.java:572) - Executing prepared SQL statement [select ut.email_id, ur.authority from user_table ut, user_roles ur where ut.user_id=ur.user_id and lower(ut.email_id)=lower(?)]
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (DataSourceUtils.java:110) - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (DataSourceUtils.java:327) - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (AbstractBeanFactory.java:246) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'authSuccessHandler'
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (AbstractBeanFactory.java:246) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl#0'
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.java:106) - Adding transactional method 'rowCount' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource.java:65) - Caching method [CacheKey[admin.dao.StateDAO; public abstract java.lang.Long admin.dao.service.StateService.rowCount()]] with attributes [ROLE_ADMIN]
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (AbstractBeanFactory.java:246) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:366) - Creating new transaction with name [admin.dao.StateDAO.rowCount]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (JpaTransactionManager.java:369) - Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@84ff11] for JPA transaction
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (JpaTransactionManager.java:408) - Not exposing JPA transaction [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@84ff11] as JDBC transaction because JpaDialect [org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect@d9dbb8] does not support JDBC Connection retrieval
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:194) - Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public abstract java.lang.Long admin.dao.service.StateService.rowCount(); target is of class [admin.dao.StateDAO]; Attributes: [ROLE_ADMIN]
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (AbstractBeanFactory.java:246) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'authSuccessHandler'
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (AbstractBeanFactory.java:246) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl#0'
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:844) - Initiating transaction rollback
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (JpaTransactionManager.java:534) - Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@84ff11]
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (JpaTransactionManager.java:594) - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@84ff11] after transaction
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:338) - Closing JPA EntityManager
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:346) - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:347) - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:348) - Delegating to authentication failure handler loginsuccesshandler.AuthenticationFailureHandler@14883a3
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:36) - Redirecting to '/SocialNetworking/utility/Login.jsf'
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:269) - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-55] (SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:97) - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-49] (AntPathRequestMatcher.java:116) - Checking match of request : '/utility/login.jsf'; against '/utility/login.jsf*'
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-49] (AntPathRequestMatcher.java:116) - Checking match of request : '/utility/login.jsf'; against '/utility/login.jsf*'
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-49] (FilterChainProxy.java:180) - /utility/Login.jsf has an empty filter list
```

---

The last thing:

When I give up this bean and unregister from the `application-context.xml` file, the login is made successfully but the following information can be seen on the server console.

```
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-165] (HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:139) - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-165] (HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:85) - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@b910c1. A new one will be created.
```

Comment: Can you show the code of userSevice.getUser(userName) method? Can you post full exception stack trace?

Comment: @Maksym Demidas - That method is posted. The exception is consumed by Spring and therefore the full excpetion stacktrace is not available. This message is through - `sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message`. I don't know how to display the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: I am do not see anything wrong. It looks like the security context was cleared by something. I see two options to know more: 1) activate debug logging for org.springframework.security package 2) make a brekaepoint in SecurityConextholder class (for example in SecurityContextHolder.clearContext() method). Hope this helps.

Comment: @MaksymDemidas - These two statments in that event `String userName = ((UserDetails) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUsername();
        System.out.println("userName = "+userName);` display the user name. Therefore, the authentication object must be available. So, it is difficult to guess why it doesn't work with the autowired `UserService.`

Comment: Sorry, have your tried to debug the code? I am sure it will be very easy to detect the cause in debug.

Comment: Edited the question according to a new application with the same problem.

Comment: @Tiny Am having the similar issue as you see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755000/httpsession-is-now-null-but-was-not-null-at-start-of-request-session-was-inval but your solution is not working for me. I keep getting the anonymousUser authentication

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The security's authorization check part gets the authenticated object from `SecurityContext`, which will be set when a request gets through the spring security filter. My assumption here is that soon after the login this is not being set. You probably can use a hack as given below to set the value.

```
try {
    SecurityContext ctx = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(ctx);
    ctx.setAuthentication(event.getAuthentication());

    //Do what ever you want to do

} finally {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
}
```

Update:

Also you can have a look at the [InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/event/InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent.html) which will be called once the `SecurityContext` is set.

Comment: Yes, this indeed worked but I always doubt there must be something wonky in my application, especially in Spring Security. Thanks. :D

Comment: If you see anything else in the future, then please don't forget to let me know here because my attempts have all been finished and I don't see anything wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Yes as the my first comment implies, it works with the code you gave but I feel there should be something wrong in my application (and therefore this code is needed) but I'm not sure at all about it because this is my third application with the same problem. Many thanks.

Comment: @Tiny did you try the second solution I provided? that seems more appropriate for me

Comment: Not yet but I will give it a try shortly (since I was a little busy with JSF/Primefaces). Thanks.

Comment: @Tiny that was something I came across recently when I was debugging some issue by stepping through the spring security code

Comment: Well, I will put it into practice and see if it succeeds. I will leave comments later accordingly here. Thank you.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Am having the similar issue as you answered see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755000/httpsession-is-now-null-but-was-not-null-at-start-of-request-session-was-inval but your solution is not working for me. I keep getting the anonymousUser authentication. Can you please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 17):

This could also happens if you put a `@PreAuthorize` or `@PostAuthorize` in a Bean in creation. I would recommend to move such annotations to methods of interest.

Comment: Yes, this worked for us by removing PreAuthorize. However, since, it was mandatory for us to have PreAuthorize role for any API, it was suggested to have following to have child thread inherit Parent Auth Object <br/> SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);

Answer (score 4):

As pointed already by @Arun P Johny the root cause of the problem is that at the moment when `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` is processed `SecurityContextHolder` is not populated by Authentication object. So any declarative authorization checks (that must get user rights from `SecurityContextHolder`) will not work. I give you another idea how to solve this problem. There are two ways how you can run your custom code immidiately after successful authentication:

1. Listen to `AuthenticationSuccessEvent`
2. Provide your custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` implementation.

`AuthenticationSuccessHandler` has one important advantage over first way: `SecurityContextHolder` will be already populated. So just move your `stateService.rowCount()` call into `loginsuccesshandler.LoginSuccessHandler#onAuthenticationSuccess(...)` method and the problem will go away.

Comment: With `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`, it works but I'm in doubt, there is something in my configurations that might not sufficiently be relied upon. Thanks. :D

Answer (score 3):

There is similar issue. I added listener as given here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145936/spring-security-j-spring-security-logout-problem

It worked for me adding below lines to web.xml.
Posting it very late, should help someone looking for answer.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class> org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Are you talking about this listener, `org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher`? I have also this listener in `web.xml` as shown in the question. In that case, it would be better to add your own solution to the answer, if you could. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error while using SpringBoot 2.1.4, along with Spring Security 5 (I believe). After one day of trying everything that Google had to offer, I discovered the cause of error in my case. I had a setup of micro-services, with the Auth server being different from the Resource Server. I had the following lines in my application.yml which prevented 'auto-configuration' despite of having included dependencies `spring-boot-starter-security`, `spring-security-oauth2` and `spring-security-jwt`. I had included the following in the properties (during development) which caused the error.

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
```

Commenting it out solved it for me.

```
#spring:
#  autoconfigure:
#    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
```

Hope, it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was a ContextRefreshedEvent handler. I was doing some data initilization but at that point in the application the Authentication had not been set. It was a catch 22 since the system needed an authentication to authorize and it needed authorization to get the authentication details :). I ended up loosening the authorization from a class level to a method level.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I needed to properly disable security and implement my own preAuthorization. Unlike the OP, I was trying to disable authentication altogether and implement my own solution.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when and I solved it by using the following annotation :

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        SecurityAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class Application {...}
```

I think the behavior is the same as what Abhishek explained

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be got if you use Content-Type: application/json instead of Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0):

In my case i simply forgot to initialize spring security, this can be done by extending AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer when you use an empty web.xml file.