# How to properly access a secured Spring Data REST Repository in a ApplicationRunner?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I followed the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#security) on how to secure REST repositories with `@PreAuthorize`. However, the following repository

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface RouteRepository extends SortingOnlyRepository<Route, Long> {
}
```

needs to be accessed by an `ApplicationRunner` to perform some initial setup tasks after application startup.

```java
@Component
public class RouteBuilder implements ApplicationRunner {
    private final RouteRepository repository;

    public RouteBuilder(RouteRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        repository.findAll()
                .stream()
                // do something
                ;
    }
}
```

Since there's no security context active when this runner is executed the application won't start at all

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
Caused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

What are my options to access the REST repository properly? I'm thinking of

- Populating a *fake* `Authentication` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16727172/5006866)
- Decouple concerns and just don't use a REST repository for this use case
- Configure security in a `WebSecurityConfig` alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is to populate a proper (fake) security context and is actually given in the official [Spring Data REST + Spring Security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/security) example.

Adapted from [`Application`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/rest/security/src/main/java/example/springdata/rest/security/Application.java#L64):

```java
try {
    SecurityUtils.runAs("system", "system", "ROLE_ADMIN");

    repository.findAll()
                .stream()
                // do something
                ;
} finally {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
}
```

Where [`SecurityUtils`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/rest/security/src/main/java/example/springdata/rest/security/SecurityUtils.java#L45) is

```java
public static void runAs(String username, String password, String... roles) {
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(roles)));
}
```